# Is it possible to add fields to the data returned by the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I would like to get the `category` of a page like when I retrieve a user's likes. I've [read the doc on facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/likes/), but it doesn't mention adding additional fields. Is it possible to specify fields that are returned in the `data` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#reading

> You can choose the fields or edges that you want returned with the
>   fields query parameter